# Variance of a random variable conditional on being greater than 0

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, variance

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f(x)$. Let $Y$ be defined as follows:
$$
Y = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
&0,\qquad &X \le A\\
&X - A,\qquad &A \lt X \le L\\
&L - A,\qquad &X \gt L
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

$E(Y|Y>0)$ should be:
$$
\frac{\int_A^L (x-A) f(x)\;dx + (L-A) \int_L^\infty f(x)\;dx}{\int_A^\infty f(x)\;dx}
$$

Am I correct in my assumption that the variance of $Y$ conditional on $Y > 0$ is $E(Y^2|Y > 0) - (E(Y|Y > 0) ) ^ 2$ where $E(Y^2|Y > 0)$ is:
$$
\frac{\int_A^L (x-A)^2 f(x)\;dx + (L-A)^2 \int_L^\infty f(x)\;dx}{\int_A^\infty f(x)\;dx}
$$
in other words, is Var$(Y|Y > 0)$ equal to:
$$
\frac{\int_A^L (x-A)^2 f(x)\;dx + (L-A)^2 \int_L^\infty f(x)\;dx}{\int_A^\infty f(x)\;dx} - \left(\frac{\int_A^L (x-A) f(x)\;dx + (L-A) \int_L^\infty f(x)\;dx}{\int_A^\infty f(x)\;dx}\right)^2
$$

Similarly, for the case:
$$
Z = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
&0,\qquad &X \le A\\
&X - A,\qquad &A \lt X \le L\\
&0,\qquad &X \gt L
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

$E(Z|Z > 0)$ would be
$$
\frac{\int_A^L (x-A) f(x)\;dx}{\int_A^L f(x)\;dx}
$$

and would Var$(Z|Z > 0)$ then equal:
$$
\frac{\int_A^L (x-A)^2 f(x)\;dx}{\int_A^L f(x)\;dx} - \left(\frac{\int_A^L (x-A) f(x)\;dx}{\int_A^L f(x)\;dx}\right)^2
$$

Thank you.

Comment: Please avoid unnecessary `\large` (that is, all of them).

Comment: @Did Sorry, my eyes aren't what they used to be and it was easier for me to see.

Comment: Please correct obvious typos: the first $x-A$ should read $X-A$, the first $X>A$ should read $X>L$, the first $(x-a)$ should read $(x-A)$, the first $(L-A) + \int_L^\infty f(x)\;dx$ should read $(L-A)\int_L^\infty f(x)\;dx$, and so on.

Comment: @Did Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expressions for $\mathbb{E}[Y|Y>0]$ and $\operatorname{var}[Y|Y>0]$ are correct. They are immediate consequences of the fact that $Y>0$ implies $X>0$ and standard results on the distribution of a truncated random variable. See, e.g. [the wikipedia page on truncated distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution).

Likewise, your expressions for $\mathbb{E}[Z|Z>0]$ and $\operatorname{var}[Z|Z>0]$ are both correct too, as $Z>0$ implies $A<X<L$.